# AWS CloudFormation : attribute PathPart must be a readonly property

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to describe my resources on an AWS CloudFormation template. I'm trying to insert in the template the permissions needed by the APIGateway to invoke a Lambda function.

Through the documentation available for CF I have seen that the type of resource I need is an AWS::Lambda::Permission, that I went to build like this

```
    SampleApiPermission:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
        Properties:
          Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
          FunctionName: "HelloWorldFunction"
          Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
          SourceArn: !Join
            - ''
            - - !Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:'
              - !Ref RestApiHelloWorld
              - "/"
              - !Ref APIStageHelloWorld
              - "/POST/"
              - !GetAtt APIGatawayResourceHelloWorld.PathPart
```

So however he gives me an error: "Requested attribute PathPart must be a readonly property in schema for AWS::ApiGateway::Resource". I also tried to use !Ref but in that case it takes me the resource ID and then the result is wrong. I tried to make one last try to see if the rest was wrong, but putting the part I need directly as the string everything works as it should

```
    SampleApiPermission:
        Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
        Properties:
          Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
          FunctionName: "HelloWorldFunction"
          Principal: "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
          SourceArn: !Join
            - ''
            - - !Sub 'arn:aws:execute-api:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:'
              - !Ref RestApiHelloWorld
              - "/"
              - !Ref APIStageHelloWorld
              - "/POST/"
              - "helloworld"
```

I would like to understand if it is possible in some way to obtain that value or if it is not possible and must necessarily enter it as a string. Thank you in advance for your attention and the time you will use to help me.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for "Requested attribute PathPart must be a readonly property in schema for AWS::ApiGateway::Resource" is that PathPart is not Return Value of AWS::ApiGateway::Resource. The only Return Value is ResourceId. The doucmentation can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-resource.html

Maybe you could try to use AWS SAM extension for CloudFormation which should help to streamline building API Gateway and Lambda Functions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-resource-api--examples

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem with a cloudformation property from RDS ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html#cfn-rds-dbcluster-port)).
Error when copilot tries to build the cloudformation template:

```
Requested attribute Port must be a **readonly** property in schema for AWS
    ::RDS::DBCluster. Rollback requested by user.
```

My template had:

```
dbPort:
    Description: "Port number of the Aurora DB writer instance"
    Value: !GetAtt odooproddbDBCluster.Port
```

In my template, we need to remove: `Description:` line as it is trying to change/set a **read-only property**. Just get the value and remove other operations in the template.

PS. there is a different way to access the Port property via:

```
odooproddbDBCluster.Endpoint.Port
```

but its NOT an integer! (Review docs for your resource)
We need ports to be integers in manifest.yml or other places.